# fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: gcc, g++

I recently change my OS to the last mint cinamon. Compiling one of the library I need (and that I used to used without problem), I get this message:

```
fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

I don't know what to do.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including directory `/usr/local/include/eigen3/` solved this for me.

Like this, for example:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/eigen3/ CODE.cpp -o EXECUTABLE
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to install eigen3 library,

on Ubuntu it would be

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```